# Strange battery behavior (not discharging)

Tags: battery, sensors

Lately my laptop got this problem. Right after i unplug it (with full charge battery) it says that the duration remaining is about 30 minutes. 
Then, after few seconds, it drops from 100% to 90/96% and says that there are 20 minutes remaining and then it drop pretty fast.

But that's only one part of the problem. Once it reaches 8/9% it stops discharging and it lasts for even 3/4 hours.

The initial discharge is independent from the power consume (i mean, it drops at the same speed even if i am in super power saving mode or with everything maxed out).
I thought that the battery sensor may be damaged (maybe because of the heat?) or is the battery itself?

My laptop is a Toshiba Satellite L50-A

Comment: I'm using windows 10, but it has been tested with windows 8 and linux too and still have the same problem

Comment: You may have a look in the BIOS or manufacturer utilities if there is a calibrate battery function.  It performs a complete charge/discharge/charge cycle and adjusts the values reported to the OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is entirely possible that the battery is dying and just needs replacing.

One of the real problems with batteries is that it is actually quite difficult to estimate how much charge they have left. Typically it is done by applying a specific load and seeing what the voltage sags down to and then looking at a graph of thousands of complete battery discharges and seeing where you are on the graph.

The problem is that if the battery contact has eroded slightly or a film has built up on it then it will make it more difficult for current to flow through it. This causes the apparent resistance to increase and increases the voltage dropped when a current is applied. The result is that it *appears* to the outside world that the battery is much later in the discharge cycle than it really is. It can still supply pretty much all of the charge, but something is causing the voltage to be a lot lower.

Windows (and other operating systems) will just be showing you what the battery is reporting, that the voltage from the battery is lower and therefore is probably (as far as they know) mostly discharged.

Effectively you end up with the battery cells being able store charge, but not able to release it as efficiently as it used to. This might also result in the battery getting warmer than it used to.

If I were you then I would get a new battery and take your old one to a local disposal centre.